# Data Not inserting into Database JPA+Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

actually I have created Entity Beans which are used to create  tables in mysql database, everything is working fine with transaction  classes using entityfactory.

Now I need this functionality...when I deploy the EAR file in  application sever JBOSS..it have to check whether the tables are  existing in the database or not..if they are not present..it have to  create the tables automatically..of course I have specified this  function hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update in persistence.xml..but still not  creating any tables which are not present in the database and not  throwing any error also when ever I run the application server its creating only mysql default tables..but not the developed ones and here I am give my code:

```
package com.ernst.persistenceImpl.beanImpl;

import com.ernst.persistenceAPI.beanAPI.NrKreiseBeanAPI;
import com.ernst.persistenceAPI.localBeanAPI.NrKreiseLocalBeanAPI;
import com.ernst.persistenceAPI.remoteBeanAPI.NrKreiseRemoteBeanAPI;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "NR_KREISE")
public class NrKreiseBean implements NrKreiseBeanAPI, NrKreiseLocalBeanAPI,
NrKreiseRemoteBeanAPI, Serializable {

    @Id
    private int nr_kreise_id;

    @Basic
    private int fk_nr_typ;

    @Basic
    private int data_ref_von;

    @Basic
    private int data_ref_bis;

    @Basic
    private int data_ref;

    @Basic
    private int msg_ref_von;

    @Basic
    private int msg_ref_bis;

    @Basic
    private int msg_ref;

    @Basic
    private String desc;

    public int getNr_kreise_id() {
        return nr_kreise_id;
    }

    public void setNr_kreise_id(int nr_kreise_id) {
        this.nr_kreise_id = nr_kreise_id;
    }

    public int getFk_nr_typ() {
        return fk_nr_typ;
    }

    public void setFk_nr_typ(int fk_nr_typ) {
        this.fk_nr_typ = fk_nr_typ;
    }

    public int getData_ref_von() {
        return data_ref_von;
    }

    public void setData_ref_von(int data_ref_von) {
        this.data_ref_von = data_ref_von;
    }

    public int getData_ref_bis() {
        return data_ref_bis;
    }

    public void setData_ref_bis(int data_ref_bis) {
        this.data_ref_bis = data_ref_bis;
    }

    public int getData_ref() {
        return data_ref;
    }

    public void setData_ref(int data_ref) {
        this.data_ref = data_ref;
    }

    public int getMsg_ref_von() {
        return msg_ref_von;
    }

    public void setMsg_ref_von(int msg_ref_von) {
        this.msg_ref_von = msg_ref_von;
    }

    public int getMsg_ref_bis() {
        return msg_ref_bis;
    }

    public void setMsg_ref_bis(int msg_ref_bis) {
        this.msg_ref_bis = msg_ref_bis;
    }

    public int getMsg_ref() {
        return msg_ref;
    }

    public void setMsg_ref(int msg_ref) {
        this.msg_ref = msg_ref;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

Persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="DefaultDS" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.ernst.persistenceImpl.beanImpl.NrKreiseBean</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
                value="persistence-units/DefaultDS" />
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile"
                      value="WEB-INF.classes.META-INF.hibernate.cfg.xml" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                      value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
                      value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lagerstandnew" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="sekhar" />

            <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection"
                      value="class, hbm" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"
                      value="create" />
            <!-- SQL stdout logging -->
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Can any one please give me an idea how to do this or please tell me if I have done anything wrong in above files.

Thanks in Advance.

Best Regards,
Raja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following persistence.xml works perfectly

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="lagerstand_local" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <non-jta-data-source>dataSource</non-jta-data-source>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.ernst.ernstWeb.mySqlDialectExtended.MySqlDialectExtended"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lagerstand?autoReconnect=true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="sekhar"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="hbm, class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="use_sql_comments" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your tables are actually being created in the database pointed to by the DefaultDS? In a standard JBoss environment that is a HypersonicSQL database. I would remove all DefaultDS references from your configuration.

Comment: but here its creating default tables in the database named lagerstandnew..but not the required tables.

Answer (score 0):

> (...) also when ever I run the application server its creating only mysql default tables but not the developed ones

Unless you overrode the `hsqldb-ds.xml` file, you are not connecting to the database you think you are.

When you deploy your application on JBoss, the persistence provider is using the JTA data source who's global JNDI name is specified by the following element:

```
<jta-data-source>java:/DefaultDS</jta-data-source>
```

And not the built-in connection pool that you configure using hibernate specific `properties`.

If you want to connect to your MySQL database,

1. create a data source pointing on it
2. use this data source in your `persistence.xml`.

For step #1, see [Chapter 8. Using other Databases](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/getting_started/v4/html/db.html) (they provide a MySQL based example).

For step #2, a typicall `persistence.xml` would be (assuming the MySQL data source is `MySqlDS`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="DefaultDS" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.ernst.persistenceImpl.beanImpl.NrKreiseBean</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile"
                      value="WEB-INF.classes.META-INF.hibernate.cfg.xml" />

            <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection"
                      value="class, hbm" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"
                      value="create" />
            <!-- SQL stdout logging -->
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply..actually I am using almost same xml file except jndi name because in mysql-ds.xml file I am using DefaultDS as my jndi name..but its not creating required tables in database lagerstandnew but its creating default tables in the database.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply..actually I am using almost same xml file except jndi name because in mysql-ds.xml file I am using DefaultDS as my jndi name..but its not creating required tables in database lagerstandnew but its creating default tables in the database. These are the steps I have done upto now. Step 1: Created Entity Beans. Step 2: created persistence.xml file and then created an EAR file and deployed in JBOSS after changing the configuration of mysql-ds.xml file according to my configurations. So please tell me what more I have to do to auto generate the mysql tables.